# Generating a random float with a controlled precision level

Tags: ruby

This generates a random float with a certain precision level in Ruby:

```
def generate(min,max,precision)
  number = rand * (max - min) + min
  factor = 10.0 ** precision
  return (number * factor).to_i / factor 
end
```

Someone recently suggested me that it may be simpler to do this:

```
var = rand(100) * 1.0    
var /= 10
```

Which generates a random float from 0.0 to 10.0.

This sounds good, but I'm not sure about how to control the precision level with that method. How may I make the equivalent to my first method, but using this suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a range `x1` to `x2`, and you want a minimum increment ("precision") of delta, then you need

```
n = (x2 - x1)/delta +1
```

Different integers, which you scale with

```
rand(n) * delta + x1
```

To give random numbers between `x1` and `x2` inclusive, with an increment of `delta`

How do you define "precision"? The relationship between `delta` and `precision` is given ( according to you formula) by

```
Delta = 10**(-precision)
```

Or

```
delta = 1.0 / 10**precision
```